# MQTT-like Publish-Subscribe with Python and WebSockets?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I'm working on a project that needs a framework to handle pub/sub connections between a webpage and Python.

I've already used mosquitto (an open-source implementation of MQTT) and it worked, but the server needs a modded Apache module to redirect WebSocket connections to the broker.

Right now, I'm looking at Tornado but it doesn't fit on my requirements. I need a solution for the follwing:

- A web page connects to a python server or some kind of broker and subscribes a topic do receive data associated with that topic.
- Every time Python has data associated with that topic (let's say every 10 seconds), the data is sent to the specific client (or clients) that subscribed to that topic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could try the HiveMQ* MQTT broker instead of mosquitto as that has MQTT over websocket support built in.

- http://www.hivemq.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) provides Publish & Subscribe (and RPC) over WebSocket via the [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) protocol, and comes with client for JS (besides others) and Python/Twisted for server.

Here is a complete [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp/pubsub/simple/example1).

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score 0):

[websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) provides a websockets to tcp proxy that you could put in front of mosquitto. You would have to run it on a different port than 80 if you already have a web server of course, but it is easier than dealing with custom apache/lighttpd modules.